# Word 2007, company wide defaults?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, themes, templates

In our company we have a default Word 2003 template which replaced the Normal.dot

I see in Word 2007, I think I can do something similar but there are also themes, what would be the best practice to distribute a set of company wide styles? Templates or themes?

If one of them, can I distribute theme to other users to a path where their Word will automatically use the theme as default?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few grammatical errors in your question and the question title does not really do justice to the body of your question. It is a good question, however you may want to consider editing. The quality of help you'll receive is often proportional to the quality of how the question is asked.

My recommendation would be to distribute the company-style set in a global template. My opinion is that Themes are limiting since not all styles are 'theme aware', and Themes are only supported by the Open XML Format (no .doc files).

Further note that with custom Themes you will now have to deploy four files instead of just one template. Separate files for the colors, effects, fonts, and then the mother .thmx file. The default path to themes is:

> %appdata%\Microsoft\Templates\Document
>   Themes